# Angular7 - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I'm trying to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.glify) plugin for leaflet. I need the WebGL drawing because I have a lot of POIs, and the standard leaflet just doesn't cut it.

When I import the plugin I get the following error while trying to serve to localhost:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/leaflet.glify/src/js/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ...
```

I tried to modify the package.json with this code:

```
...
"browser":{
    "fs":false
}
...
```

Which solves the build error, but it just won't work in the browser where I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think  `fs` is not mean to use on the web directly, since it's a Node.js module,

Comment: Try to install a prvious version 2.1.2 of this plugin

Comment: @Camilo Yeah I know, but I thought webpack would somehow solve it, I mean it's a web library so there would be no point using it with node.

Comment: @MassiIssar I tried it with multiple versions, same results.

Comment: Maybe including your webpack configuration could help solve the issue?

Comment: The project was generated by the Angular-CLI so I don't really have one.

Comment: having you tried `npm`?, install `fs` with `npm`, that should work, it did for me (if you're trying to use the package within any component, otherwise I don't know).

Comment: If this code is going to be run in the browser, it can never use the fs module nor access any server file system. Webpack will not be able to resolve fs as a browser useable module. If you need fs with angular specifically, the only way that can happen is you are using a SSR solution such as Angular Universal which is running via a server like express or .NET Core.